# Quantum Fourier Transformation Qiskit implementation

Tags: python, quantum-computing

I tried to work the Qiskit implementation using python3

```
AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'cu1'
```

is the error message

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from qiskit import *
```

Comment: cu1 is deprecated in favor of cp